# PHP: Invert order of objects in a string

Tags: php, string, foreach, operators

I have this foreach which outputs a link to a post, its name and an icon if that post is read/unread.

```
foreach (BLAHBLAH) {
    $is_read = !in_array($obj->id, $unread_msgs);
    $title = $obj->title;
    $url = $obj->url;

    $output = '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'. $title;
    if ($is_read) {
        $output .= ' <img src="icon-read.png" />';
    } else { $output .= ' <img src="icon-unread.png" />'; }
    $output .= '</a></li>';
    echo $output;
}
```

So output format is `<li><a href="POST_URL">POST_TITLE</a><img src="READ/UNREAD_ICON"/></li>`.
I'd like to have instead `<li><img src="READ/UNREAD_ICON"/><a href="POST_URL">POST_TITLE</a></li>`. So, have the image before the link.
I'm trying to play with string operators but I'm not really familiar with them.. :(

I also tried to do something like

```
$output = '<li><img src="'.$iconstatus.'"/><a href="'.url.'">'. title;
if ($is_read) {
    $iconstatus = 'icon-read.png';
} else { $iconstatus = 'icon-unread.png'; }
$output .= '</a></li>';
echo $output;
```

But doesn't seem to do any good.

Comment: your second try is senseless you want to add `$iconstantus` to `$output` before assigning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (BLAHBLAH) {
    $is_read = !in_array($obj->id, $unread_msgs);
    $title = $obj->title;
    $url = $obj->url;
    $output = "<li><a href=\"$url\">
                     <span>$title</span>
                     <img src=\"icon-".($is_read ? '' : 'un')."read.png\" alt=\"img\" />  
                   </a>
               </li>";
    echo $output;
}
```

You can simply check if it's read add proper code to `$output`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable before you set it. Try this:

```
if ($is_read) {
    $iconstatus = 'icon-read.png';
} else { $iconstatus = 'icon-unread.png'; }
$output = '<li><img src="'.$iconstatus.'"/><a href="'.$url.'">'. $title;
$output .= '</a></li>';
echo $output;
```

Of course, you can simplify the first three lines and just use this:

```
$iconstatus = $is_read ? 'icon-read.png' : 'icon-unread.png';
$output = '<li><img src="'.$iconstatus.'"/><a href="'.$url.'">'. $title;
$output .= '</a></li>';
echo $output;
```

I suggest you read up on [PHP string reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more details on how to handle strings in PHP.